# Pythonでテキストファイルの内容をリスト化してCSVで出力する

Tags: python, csv

Pythonでテキストにある内容をリスト化してCSVに出力したいのですが、やり方が分からなくて困っています。
調べたものでコードを作ってみたのですが、想像している動きではないので皆様のお力が欲しいです。

**対象のテキストファイル**

```
名前:A
クラス:B
学年:C
成績:D

名前:AA
クラス:BB
学年:CC
成績:DD
```

以上の `:` 以降の内容を、Pythonで次のようにリスト化し

- `[A,B,C,D]`
- `[AA,BB,CC,DD]`

さらに最終的に `,` で区切ってCSVに出力したいです（下図の通り）。

[image: 期待されるExcel出力]

自分では以下のようなPythonコードが書けましたが、これをより短いコードで、期待通りの出力を得られるようにする方法をご教示いただけますと幸いです。

**現状のコード:**

```
with open(r"txtファイル",encoding='utf-8') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    stat = 0
    for line in lines:
        if stat == 0:
            if(line.startswith("名前:")):
                print(line.strip("名前:"))
                stat = 1

    for line in lines:
        if stat == 1:
            if(line.startswith("クラス")):
                print(line.strip("クラス:"))
                stat = 2

    for line in lines:
        if stat == 2:
            if(line.startswith("学年:")):
                print(line.strip("学年:"))
                stat = 3

    for line in lines:
        if stat == 3:
            if(line.startswith("成績:")):
                print(line.strip("成績:"))
```

Comment: If文を使って「テキストに‘名前‘が出てきたら、名前以降の’A’と’AA’を抽出してリスト化、次にテキストに’クラス’が出てきたら、クラス以降の’B’と’BB’を抽出してリスト化というのを繰り返して、Python上で[A,B,C,D]のようにリスト化する場合はどのようなコードにすればよろしいでしょうか。お力添えいただけると幸いです。

Comment: 質問の入力テキストなどは本来の形式で示してください。全角コロン使用したテキスト内容提示すると, 回答もそれに応じたものになります。

Comment: 回答で問題が解決した場合, 「プラス投票」「回答の承認」など行うとよいかもです。参考: [自分の質問に誰かが回答してくれたらどうしたらいいですか？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

###### Pandas モジュールを使う場合

```py
import pandas as pd

with open(r'result_sheet.txt', encoding='utf-8') as f:
  records = [
    dict(j.split(':') for j in i.split('\n') if j)
    for i in f.read().replace('\r', '').split('\n\n') if i
  ]


df = pd.DataFrame(records)
df.to_excel('result_sheet.xlsx', index=False)
```

[image: table]

###### CSV モジュールを使う場合

```py
import csv

with open(r'result_sheet.txt', encoding='utf-8') as f:
  records = [
    dict(j.split('：') for j in i.split('\n') if j)
    for i in f.read().replace('\r', '').split('\n\n') if i
  ]

with open('result_sheet.csv', 'w') as f:
  writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=records[0].keys())
  writer.writeheader()
  for r in records:
    writer.writerow(r)
```

**result_sheet.csv**

```
名前,クラス,学年,成績
A,B,C,D
AA,BB,CC,DD
```

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。
CSVモジュールの方を使わせて頂いたのですが、このようなエラーが出てしまいました。
「dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required」

Comment: おそらく、"："(FULLWIDTH COLON)で区切られていない行があるのだと思います。もしかして、区切り文字は ASCII の ":"(colon) でしょうか？

Comment: 遅くなってしまい申し訳ございません。
はい、ASCIIの”：”です。

Comment: `dict(j.split(':') for j in i.split('\n') if j)` に変更しました。

Comment: ありがとうございます！
解決しました！

Answer (score 0):

pandas と openpyxl がインストールされている環境で
成績：D

名前：AA
の「成績：D」と「名前：AA」の間が改行だけの空行の前提になります。

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_table(r"txtファイル", encoding='utf-8', header=None, engine='python', sep=':')
item_num = len(set(df.values[:,0]))
ary = df.values[:,1].reshape(-1, item_num)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(ary, columns=df.values[0:item_num,0])
df2.to_excel('data2.xlsx', header=True, index=False)
```

標準のリスト型のデータが欲しい場合は、上記 ary からリストにしてください。

```
lst = list(map(list, ary))
print(lst)
# [['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], ['AA', 'BB', 'CC', 'DD']]
```

Comment: すみません : を全角と勘違いしました。
df = pd.read_table(r"txtファイル",　encoding='utf-8', header=None, engine='python', sep='：')
を
df = pd.read_table(r"txtファイル",　encoding='utf-8', header=None, sep=':')
にしてください。