# pythonの実行方法

Tags: python

Pythonで以下のようなテキストファイルから、出力結果をリストで出力したい場合のコードをご教示いただけますでしょうか。

**対象のテキストファイル:**
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

**期待する出力結果:**

```
["株式会社〇〇〇　帯広太郎様","株式会社〇〇〇","営業部","帯広太郎","オビヒロタロウ","123-4567","株式会社〇〇〇","0120-111-111","000-000-000","obihirotaro.com","紙について","代表者様へのご提案【相談したい】"]
```

---

自分で出来たのは以下のコードで、行ごとに処理したのですが、それで止まってしまいました。

**現状のコード:**

```
fileobj = open(r"〇〇〇.txt", encoding="utf_8")
while True:
line = fileobj.readline()
if line:
row_no += 1
print(row_no, ":", line)
else:
break
```

Comment: そのままではありませんが、こちらの記事 [Pythonでテキストファイルの内容をリスト化してCSVで出力する](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/86604/26370) の内容が近いでしょう。こちらを参考に改造していってはどうでしょう？

Comment: 何を行いたいか をもう少し詳しく記してみてください。pythonの `list`型のデータ？ それとも一覧という意味の「リスト」でしょうか？
行頭の数文字が省かれてるっぽいけど, 取り除きたいのか単なる記述ミスなのか。あと Pythonではインデント(字下げ)は重要な意味を持つので, 字下げなしだと混乱します(記載ミスなのか, 間違ったコードなのか判らない)

Comment: おそらく1つのファイルで1件の問い合わせ内容(問い合わせメールフォーム)を示している。':'の前はフォームの入力項目名で、CSVでならばヘッダーに相当するが、リストをそのまま連結することを想定してリストにヘッダーは出力しない、といったあたりでしょう。それと質問には記述されていませんが、最後の「お問い合わせ内容」は複数行になるのが普通でしょう。そしてそれは1つの項目にまとめて入れておく必要があるはずです。その辺の詳細を追記してみてください。

Answer (score 1):

[Pythonでテキストファイルの内容をリスト化してCSVで出力する](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/86604/26370)
コメントに書いたような仕様であるならば、上記記事の @metropolis さんの回答を参考にして、以下のように出来るでしょう。

```
#### 'お問い合わせ内容'に複数行を許すためにいったんデータ読み込みだけ行う
with open(r'〇〇〇.txt', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    d = f.read()

#### ファイル末尾の空白および空白行を削除する
d = d.rstrip()

#### ':'の存在する行だけ処理していったん辞書を作成する
records = dict(j.split(':') for j in d.split('\n') if ':' in j)

#### 最後の':'以後を切り出して'お問い合わせ内容'に挿入する
contents = d[(d.rindex(':')+1):]
records['お問い合わせ内容'] = contents

#### 辞書の値だけ取り出してリストにする
result = list(records.values())
```

ただし、WindowsのPython 3.10.4 の環境(が原因かどうかわかりませんが)では、`株式会社〇〇〇　帯広太郎様`の全角空白文字が`\u3000`になって、`株式会社〇〇〇\u3000帯広太郎様`と表示されてしまいます。`d = f.read()`を行っただけの結果が既にそうなっているので、`open()`のパラメータか何かで調整できるのかもしれません。

ちなみに文字列を示すクォーテーションはダブルクォーテーションではなくシングルクォーテーションが使われますが。

Comment: ありがとうございます。
大変助かりました！！